# Calling a singleton method within the singleton class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module, singleton

Consider the following Ruby code:

```
module MyModule
  class << self

    def process_item(item)
      item.capitalize
    end

    def foo=(item)
      @foo_ref=process_item(item)
    end

    def foo
      @foo_ref
    end

    self.foo = "initial foo"
  end
end
```

I want to set a default `foo_ref` variable inside the singleton class definition. However, the Ruby interpreter raises the following error:

> singleton class': undefined method `foo=' for #(NoMethodError)

If I change `self.foo = "Initial foo"` to `foo = "Initial foo"` then I am creating a local variable within the singleton class, instead of calling the setter method.

Also, I do realize that I may have to put the `process_item` method in the module definition, outside the singleton class definition, so that it does not become a singleton method, but rather a helper method.

What would be the proper approach to this code (being able to call a singleton method within the singleton class definition, and having helper methods available within the singleton class definition)?

Comment: Inside a class definition, `self` is the class, so just like the error message says, you are calling the `foo=` method on the singleton class, and this method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the default value as:

```
module MyModule
  class << self

    def process_item(item)
      item.capitalize
    end

    def foo=(item)
      @foo_ref=process_item(item)
    end

    def foo
      @foo_ref ||= "initial foo"
    end
  end
end
```

What you were trying to do was to set foo to the singleton class, instead of setting foo to the class.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a nice solution to set the `foo_ref` instance variable to an initial value. Thanks!

Is there any other way to set this variable from within the class definition (access the metaclass instead of the singleton class)?

Comment: You can do it form `MyModule` scope using `self.foo=` also. (After `class << self` definition)

Comment: Seemed so obvious! Thank you very much for helping me :D